# MongoDB aggregation re-group deep nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Good day all,

I need some help figuring out this aggregation issue. I have a document with nested arrays where I want to perform lookups on the nested array's values after which I want to restore the document to its original structure. see below:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcef",
        "primary_language": "en",
        "image_link": "avatar_image_linl",
        "description": ["Some description text here"],
        "source": "community",
        "standard": "imperial",
        "gender": "male",
        "base_a": 47,
        "base_w": 220,
        "base_h": 71.65,
        "status": "draft",
        "date_created": "2023-01-18T14:14:26.201Z",
        "product_plan": {
            "p_len": 4,
            "p_fre": 1,
            "p_qua": 4,
            "avg_len": 3583,
            "total_wor": 16,
            "total_exe": 128,
            "plan": {
                "field_we": 1,
                "field_da": 1,
                "field_ti": 1,
                "field_rest_we": false,
                "field_rest_da": false,
                "product": {
                    "name": "W111",
                    "comment": {
                        "en": ""
                    },
                    "pro_diff": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Intermediate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_int": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Moderate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_dur": 3736,
                    "nbr_exe": 8,
                    "target_mus": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 1,
                            "description": "Adominorus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 16,
                            "description": "Tricerus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 5,
                            "description": "Chiwawak"
                        }
                    ],
                    "target_are": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 1,
                            "description": "Adominorus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 4,
                            "description": "Chiwawak"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Amanus"
                        }
                    ],
                    "items": {
                        "itemid": 44,
                        "target_are": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 4,
                                "description": "Chiwawak"
                            }
                        ],
                        "target_mus": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 5,
                                "description": "Chiwawak"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nbr_ref": 4,
                        "int_rec": "06~10",
                        "type_rec": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 14,
                                "description": "Straight Set"
                            }
                        ],
                        "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                        "rest_time": 90,
                        "note": "",
                        "order": null,
                        "pro_dur": 520,
                        "_id": "63ca9b798d47745ae5589906",
                        "status": 0,
                        "pct_complete": 0,
                        "set": []
                    },
                    "isCustomName": false,
                    "status": 0,
                    "pct_complete": 0
                },
                "_id": "63ca95368d47745ae558985e"
            },
            "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcf0"
        },
        "title": "Short Title text here",
        "itemID": "bodyfyme882212-1674051266.214",
        "__v": 32
    },
    {
        "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcef",
        "primary_language": "en",
        "image_link": "avatar_image_linl",
        "description": ["Some description text here"],
        "source": "community",
        "standard": "imperial",
        "gender": "male",
        "base_a": 47,
        "base_w": 220,
        "base_h": 71.65,
        "status": "draft",
        "date_created": "2023-01-18T14:14:26.201Z",
        "product_plan": {
            "p_len": 4,
            "p_fre": 1,
            "p_qua": 4,
            "avg_len": 3583,
            "total_wor": 16,
            "total_exe": 128,
            "plan": {
                "field_we": 1,
                "field_da": 1,
                "field_ti": 1,
                "field_rest_we": false,
                "field_rest_da": false,
                "product": {
                    "name": "W111",
                    "comment": {
                        "en": ""
                    },
                    "pro_diff": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Intermediate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_int": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Moderate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_dur": 3736,
                    "nbr_exe": 8,
                    "target_mus": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 1,
                            "description": "Adominorus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 16,
                            "description": "Tricerus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 5,
                            "description": "Chiwawak"
                        }
                    ],
                    "target_are": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 1,
                            "description": "Adominorus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 4,
                            "description": "Chiwawak"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Amanus"
                        }
                    ],
                    "items": {
                        "itemid": 339,
                        "target_are": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 4,
                                "description": "Chiwawak"
                            }
                        ],
                        "target_mus": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 5,
                                "description": "Chiwawak"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nbr_ref": 3,
                        "int_rec": "06~10",
                        "type_rec": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 14,
                                "description": "Straight Set"
                            }
                        ],
                        "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                        "rest_time": 90,
                        "note": "",
                        "order": null,
                        "pro_dur": 390,
                        "_id": "63ca9b798d47745ae5589907",
                        "status": 0,
                        "pct_complete": 0,
                        "set": []
                    },
                    "isCustomName": false,
                    "status": 0,
                    "pct_complete": 0
                },
                "_id": "63ca95368d47745ae558985e"
            },
            "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcf0"
        },
        "title": "Short Title text here",
        "itemID": "bodyfyme882212-1674051266.214",
        "__v": 32
    },
        {
        "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcef",
        "primary_language": "en",
        "image_link": "avatar_image_linl",
        "description": ["Some description text here"],
        "source": "community",
        "standard": "imperial",
        "gender": "male",
        "base_a": 47,
        "base_w": 220,
        "base_h": 71.65,
        "status": "draft",
        "date_created": "2023-01-18T14:14:26.201Z",
        "product_plan": {
            "p_len": 4,
            "p_fre": 1,
            "p_qua": 4,
            "avg_len": 3583,
            "total_wor": 16,
            "total_exe": 128,
            "plan": {
                "field_we": 1,
                "field_da": 2,
                "field_ti": 1,
                "field_rest_we": false,
                "field_rest_da": false,
                "product": {
                    "name": "W121",
                    "comment": {
                        "en": ""
                    },
                    "pro_diff": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Intermediate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_int": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Moderate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_dur": 2674,
                    "nbr_exe": 6,
                    "target_mus": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 9,
                            "description": "Lats"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 10,
                            "description": "Lower Back"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 11,
                            "description": "Middle Back"
                        }
                    ],
                    "target_are": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 3,
                            "description": "Back"
                        }
                    ],
                    "items": {
                        "itemid": 47,
                        "target_are": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 3,
                                "description": "Back"
                            }
                        ],
                        "target_mus": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 10,
                                "description": "Lower Back"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nbr_ref": 4,
                        "int_rec": "06~10",
                        "type_rec": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 14,
                                "description": "Straight Set"
                            }
                        ],
                        "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                        "rest_time": 90,
                        "note": "",
                        "order": null,
                        "pro_dur": 520,
                        "_id": "63caa1568d47745ae5589b25",
                        "status": 0,
                        "pct_complete": 0,
                        "set": []
                    },
                    "isCustomName": false,
                    "status": 0,
                    "pct_complete": 0
                },
                "_id": "63ca9b8e8d47745ae558994b"
            },
            "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcf0"
        },
        "title": "Short Title text here",
        "itemID": "bodyfyme882212-1674051266.214",
        "__v": 32
    },
    {
        "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcef",
        "primary_language": "en",
        "image_link": "avatar_image_linl",
        "description": ["Some description text here"],
        "source": "community",
        "standard": "imperial",
        "gender": "male",
        "base_a": 47,
        "base_w": 220,
        "base_h": 71.65,
        "status": "draft",
        "date_created": "2023-01-18T14:14:26.201Z",
        "product_plan": {
            "p_len": 4,
            "p_fre": 1,
            "p_qua": 4,
            "avg_len": 3583,
            "total_wor": 16,
            "total_exe": 128,
            "plan": {
                "field_we": 1,
                "field_da": 2,
                "field_ti": 1,
                "field_rest_we": false,
                "field_rest_da": false,
                "product": {
                    "name": "W121",
                    "comment": {
                        "en": ""
                    },
                    "pro_diff": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Intermediate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_int": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Moderate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_dur": 2674,
                    "nbr_exe": 6,
                    "target_mus": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 9,
                            "description": "Lats"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 10,
                            "description": "Lower Back"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 11,
                            "description": "Middle Back"
                        }
                    ],
                    "target_are": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 3,
                            "description": "Back"
                        }
                    ],
                    "items": {
                        "itemid": 495,
                        "target_are": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 3,
                                "description": "Back"
                            }
                        ],
                        "target_mus": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 11,
                                "description": "Middle Back"
                            }
                        ],
                        "nbr_ref": 3,
                        "int_rec": "10~12",
                        "type_rec": [
                            {
                                "itemID": 14,
                                "description": "Straight Set"
                            }
                        ],
                        "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                        "rest_time": 90,
                        "note": "",
                        "order": null,
                        "pro_dur": 414,
                        "_id": "63caa1568d47745ae5589b26",
                        "status": 0,
                        "pct_complete": 0,
                        "set": []
                    },
                    "isCustomName": false,
                    "status": 0,
                    "pct_complete": 0
                },
                "_id": "63ca9b8e8d47745ae558994b"
            },
            "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcf0"
        },
        "title": "Short Title text here",
        "itemID": "bodyfyme882212-1674051266.214",
        "__v": 32
    },
    {
        ......
    }
]
```

Now i want to get the document back to this structure using aggregation.

```
{
    "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcef",
    "primary_language": "en",
    "image_link": "avatar_image_linl",
    "description": ["Some description text here"],
    "source": "community",
    "standard": "imperial",
    "gender": "male",
    "base_a": 47,
    "base_w": 220,
    "base_h": 71.65,
    "status": "draft",
    "date_created": "2023-01-18T14:14:26.201Z",
    "product_plan": {
        "p_len": 4,
        "p_fre": 1,
        "p_qua": 4,
        "avg_len": 3583,
        "total_wor": 16,
        "total_exe": 128,
        // Group plan here by product_plan._id
        "plan": [
            {
                "field_we": 1,
                "field_da": 1,
                "field_ti": 1,
                "field_rest_we": false,
                "field_rest_da": false,
                "product": {
                    "name": "W111",
                    "comment": {
                        "en": ""
                    },
                    "pro_diff": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Intermediate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_int": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Moderate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_dur": 3736,
                    "nbr_exe": 8,
                    "target_mus": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 1,
                            "description": "Adominorus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 16,
                            "description": "Tricerus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 5,
                            "description": "Chiwawak"
                        }
                    ],
                    "target_are": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 1,
                            "description": "Adominorus"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 4,
                            "description": "Chiwawak"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Amanus"
                        }
                    ],
                    // group items by plan._id
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "itemid": 44,
                            "target_are": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 4,
                                    "description": "Chiwawak"
                                }
                            ],
                            "target_mus": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 5,
                                    "description": "Chiwawak"
                                }
                            ],
                            "nbr_ref": 4,
                            "int_rec": "06~10",
                            "type_rec": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 14,
                                    "description": "Straight Set"
                                }
                            ],
                            "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                            "rest_time": 90,
                            "note": "",
                            "order": null,
                            "pro_dur": 520,
                            "_id": "63ca9b798d47745ae5589906",
                            "status": 0,
                            "pct_complete": 0,
                            "set": []
                        },
                        {
                            "itemid": 339,
                            "target_are": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 4,
                                    "description": "Chiwawak"
                                }
                            ],
                            "target_mus": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 5,
                                    "description": "Chiwawak"
                                }
                            ],
                            "nbr_ref": 3,
                            "int_rec": "06~10",
                            "type_rec": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 14,
                                    "description": "Straight Set"
                                }
                            ],
                            "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                            "rest_time": 90,
                            "note": "",
                            "order": null,
                            "pro_dur": 390,
                            "_id": "63ca9b798d47745ae5589907",
                            "status": 0,
                            "pct_complete": 0,
                            "set": []
                        },
                    ],
                    "isCustomName": false,
                    "status": 0,
                    "pct_complete": 0
                },
                "_id": "63ca95368d47745ae558985e"
            },
            {
                "field_we": 1,
                "field_da": 2,
                "field_ti": 1,
                "field_rest_we": false,
                "field_rest_da": false,
                "product": {
                    "name": "W121",
                    "comment": {
                        "en": ""
                    },
                    "pro_diff": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Intermediate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_int": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 2,
                            "description": "Moderate"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pro_dur": 2674,
                    "nbr_exe": 6,
                    "target_mus": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 9,
                            "description": "Lats"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 10,
                            "description": "Lower Back"
                        },
                        {
                            "itemID": 11,
                            "description": "Middle Back"
                        }
                    ],
                    "target_are": [
                        {
                            "itemID": 3,
                            "description": "Back"
                        }
                    ],
                    // group items by plan._id
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "itemid": 47,
                            "target_are": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 3,
                                    "description": "Back"
                                }
                            ],
                            "target_mus": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 10,
                                    "description": "Lower Back"
                                }
                            ],
                            "nbr_ref": 4,
                            "int_rec": "06~10",
                            "type_rec": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 14,
                                    "description": "Straight Set"
                                }
                            ],
                            "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                            "rest_time": 90,
                            "note": "",
                            "order": null,
                            "pro_dur": 520,
                            "_id": "63caa1568d47745ae5589b25",
                            "status": 0,
                            "pct_complete": 0,
                            "set": []
                        },
                        {
                            "itemid": 495,
                            "target_are": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 3,
                                    "description": "Back"
                                }
                            ],
                            "target_mus": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 11,
                                    "description": "Middle Back"
                                }
                            ],
                            "nbr_ref": 3,
                            "int_rec": "10~12",
                            "type_rec": [
                                {
                                    "itemID": 14,
                                    "description": "Straight Set"
                                }
                            ],
                            "tempo": "1-1-1-1",
                            "rest_time": 90,
                            "note": "",
                            "order": null,
                            "pro_dur": 414,
                            "_id": "63caa1568d47745ae5589b26",
                            "status": 0,
                            "pct_complete": 0,
                            "set": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "isCustomName": false,
                    "status": 0,
                    "pct_complete": 0
                },
                "_id": "63ca9b8e8d47745ae558994b"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "63c7fec2fe9afea23afdbcf0"
    },
    "title": "Short Title text here",
    "itemID": "bodyfyme882212-1674051266.214",
    "__v": 32
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, right off the start, you have an aggregation $match on  `{ $match: { tableID: '882212-1674051266.214' } }` but you do not have a field called "tableID"...

Comment: Your samples are way too long.  Can you please simplify the problem statement and sample data?

Comment: The problem statement is I need to re-construct the document back to its original structure after unwinding and doing the lookups.

Comment: `code`
{
 itemID
 ........
 nested_Object {
  field_one,
  ........
  nested_array [
   {
    product {
     lookup_field_one
     lookup_field_two
     subProduct[{
      ........
      lookup_key_one
      lookup_key_two
      lookup_key_three
     }],
     ..........
     _id
    }
   },
   {
    product {
     lookup_field_one,
     lookup_field_two,
     subProduct[{
      ........
      lookup_key_one
      lookup_key_two
      lookup_key_three
     }],
     ..........
     _id
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
`code`

Comment: $lookup is the equivalent of a join to another collection.  Please provide an example document for the other collection.

Comment: @barrypicker I have updated the code, forget about the lookup statements. I changed it to the end documents that I want to aggregate into one document having nested of nested objects.